# "Where clause" in mapped type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Working purely on a type level. Given the following scenario:

```
type Command<Type extends string> = { type: Type };
type Handler<Type extends string, Dependencies> = (cmd: Command<Type>, deps: Dependencies) => void;

type CommandA = Command<"A">;
type CommandB = Command<"B">;

type MockServiceA = { foo: () => boolean };
type MockServiceB = { bar: () => boolean };

type HandlerA = Handler<"A", { someService: MockServiceA }>;
type HandlerB = Handler<"B", { someService: MockServiceA; anotherService: MockServiceB }>;


type HandlerSum = HandlerA | HandlerB; // there might be n handlers in the sum type
```

I would like to create a mapped type that gives me a dictionary of command types and their dependencies.

```
type OnlyHalfwayThere = {
  [K in Parameters<HandlerSum>[0]["type"]]: Parameters<HandlerSum>[1]; // <--- this gives me a union of all dependencies
};

// basically what I want is a where clause...
// get the second function argument of the handler where the first function argument matches the key selector [K in Parameters<HandlerSum>[0]["type"]]
// desired outcome
type Outcome = {
  A: { someService: MockServiceA };
  B: { someService: MockServiceA; anotherService: MockServiceB };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the mapped type like this:

```
type OnlyHalfwayThere = {
  [K in Parameters<HandlerSum> as K[0]["type"]]: K[1];
};
```

Instead of assigning the `"type"` value to `K`, we assign `Parameters<HandlerSum>` to it. We can now use `K` to get both `K[0]["type"]` and `K[1]`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)